# validate e-mail field using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a string (local part of email address) has nothing except:

- letters (a-zA-Z)
- numbers (0-9)
- underscores
- at most one dot (.)

How do I do it using `Java regex`?

Example: `a_1_b.c` and `a_b_1`, should be okay ,but `1.a_b.2` and `1_a*3` should be discarded.

Comment: Are you asking about email addresses, or about your own format? Because `foo+bar` is a valid email inbox name (as in `foo+bar@example.com`) but would be rejected by your validation

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274701/using-regular-expression-for-validating-data-is-correct-or-not if not try http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=email+address+correctness+using+regex 651K results.

Comment: it's about my own format. Rejecting `foo+bar@example.com` should be okay.

Comment: can I suggest you hit the 'edit' button and give the question a more useful title then? :)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but pretty relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156430/regexp-recognition-of-email-address-hard

Comment: And since we're are it: [an "alphabet" is a **Set of letters**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet). "a", "b", "c" are letters, not "alphabets".

Answer (score 8):

If you want to verify email correctness you might want to just rely on the [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to do it for you. Then you don't need to worry about encoding the details of the RFC 822 specification into a regex. Not to mention if you're dealing with email addresses you likely want an easy way to send them, and the library has that too. You could verify that an email address is valid with simply:

```
try {
    new InternetAddress(email).getAddress();
} catch (AddressException e) {
    // it's not valid
}
```

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel. It will allow some that OP appears to want to not allow (although, he may be looking for a simple case because he doesn't want to cover all the cases manually. Hard to tell.)

Comment: @glowcoder: good point, and it would actually allow `Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>`. One quick fix for that case would be to check that `email.equals(new InternetAddress(email).getAddress())` to verify it's not of that form.

Answer (score 2):

Your should find more information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: While partially addressing the user's issue, simply linking another page is kind of weaksauce. :-( Not gonna -1, just sayin'...

Comment: Yeah sure, but to read it and post it as ones own idea is better? This is like using google for someone else and he even wrote "it worked for me", so what's the point?

Comment: Don't post it as your own - always cite your sources. I would bring out the relevant information and put it in the post, personally. Provide it as a source and as a resource for further reading.

Comment: But that's kind of unfair to the person who wrote the Article, isn't it? I respect your comment and that you might see it as "weaksauce" but that's just your subjective **oppinion** and yours only.

Comment: It isn't just my opinion. It's widespread throughout the community here. Consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29909/is-it-ok-to-answer-questions-with-just-a-link and the answers it links. The short answer is "no." So like I said, I'm not going to downvote it, because I do think it's useful, just that it could be more so. There isn't ~much~ value added, considering (from answering questions like this myself) that particular site is usually the first result in Google.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `[\w]*\.[\w]+|[\w]+` should work, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To check your own format, this should work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[\\.]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
```

- a_1_b.c should be okay
- a_1b also
- 1.a_b.2 and 1_a*3 should get rejected

Test it on http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: the dot might or might not be there.

Comment: by question, better use `*` instead of `+` (and a '?' for the dot) - the proposed pattern requests at least 2 characters separated by a dot

Comment: You'll get a more readable regex using the CaseInsensitive flag and using `\\.?` instead of `[.]{0,1}` (within a character class no escaping for the dot) `Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9_]+\\.?[a-z0-9_]*,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there also has to be exactly one '@', and it must come before (but not immediately before) the single '.', you could do

```
final static private String charset = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]"; // separate this out for future fixes
final static priavte String regex = charset + "+@" + charset + "+\." + charset + "+";

boolean validEmail(String email) {
    return email.matches(regex);
}
```

Comment: @amdalal in that case, you're looking at the same thing with the front chopped off. `regex = charset + "+\." + charset + "+";` I left `charset` as a separate variable so if you make a change to it (adding dashes for instance) you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: no doubt leaving `charset` separate is a good idea, but the `.` might not be there in the string. i was looking for at most one dot.

Comment: So you are okay with the dot NOT being there?