# Java - Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression to validate email:

```
Validemail = ^[^\\^~`'!@$#=%&*()+|{}:;,><?\"\\/\\[\\]\\\\\\s-\\.]([^\\^~`'!@$#=%&*()+|{}:;,><?\"\\/\\[\\]\\\\\\s\\.]|\\.(?!\\.+?))*[^\\^~`'!@$#=%&*()+|{}:;,><?\"\\/\\[\\]\\\\\\s-\\.]@[^\\^~`'!@$#=%&*()+|{}:;,><?\"\\/\\[\\]\\\\\\s\\.]*[^\\^~`'!@$#=%&*()+|{}:;,><?\"\\/\\[\\]\\\\\\s-\\.]\\.(?!\\.+?)[^\\^~`'!@$#=%&*()+|{}:;,><?\"\\/\\[\\]\\\\0-9\\s-\\_]{2,40}$$
```

This validation is accepting EG:  `kate@stack---overlow.com`

However I want to restrict the domain name after `@` and before `.`  so have only 1 hyphen.

#### Update:

I would not prefer making that check using `contains` rather make it a part of regex.

Comment: Why? Would `foo@my-cool-domain.com` be allowed? Why not?

Comment: Why is there a `$$` at the end?  Perhaps your additional check would be simpler to implement as a separate check. e.g. `text.contains("--")`

Comment: @Joachim because domains with more than one hyphen isn't cool.

Comment: Also: preventing `--` would exclude all email adresses with [IDN domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

Comment: Lats disallow foo@my---cooldomain.com

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend first validating the email address with the JavaMail API, as described in this answer: [validate e-mail field using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788085/validate-e-mail-field-using-regex/5788142#5788142). That way you don't have to deal with a complicated regex to handle all of the details of the RFC 822 specification on email addresses.

Once it passes that, then add your additional check for a single hyphen after `@` and before `.`, e.g.:

```
public boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    try {
        String address = new InternetAddress(email).getAddress();
        return address.matches(".*@[^-]*-{0,1}[^-]*\\..*");
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        // you should probably log here for debugging
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah what iam saying is subsequnet hyphens we shld discourage.

Comment: If you just want to prevent sequences of hyphens then you could change the check here to `return !address.contains("--");` much like Peter suggested. The point is here though is to use the JavaMail API to do the hard work of validating an email address. Then you can easily perform your additional restriction(s) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this regex will only accept 1 `-`

```
((\w|-)+(\.\w+)?)+@[\w]+\-{0,1}[\w]+\.\w+
```